# На что заменить switch в powershell

Tags: powershell

У меня есть 3 вида вхождения статусов.
- 3 статус
- 2 статус
- 1 статус.

Эта часть кода должна при вхождении одного из статуса, присваивать этот статус одному параметру. При вхождении во 2. статус двум параметрам. 
У меня сейчас получается, что при вхождении в 1. статус, он присваивает ко всем параметрам один и тот же статус.

```
function Get-CtrlStatus() {
Param (
    # Серийный номер контроллера
    [string]$ctrlid,
    # Компонент контроллера
    [ValidateSet("main","cache","batt")][string]$ctrl_part
)

$ctrl_status = & "$ssacli" "ctrl $($ctrid_type)=$($ctrlid) show status".Split() | Where-Object {$_ -match "controller status|cache status|battery.*status"}
if ($ctrl_status.Length -eq 3) {
    switch ($ctrl_part) {
        "main" {return ($ctrl_status[0] -replace ".+:\s")}
        "cache" {return ($ctrl_status[1] -replace ".+:\s")}
        "batt" {return ($ctrl_status[2] -replace ".+:\s")}
    }
} elseif ($ctrl_status.Length -eq 2) {
    switch ($ctrl_part) {
        "main" {return ($ctrl_status[0])}
        "cache" {return ($ctrl_status[1])}
    }
} elseif ($ctrl_status.Length -eq 1) {
    switch ($ctrl_part) {
        "main" {return ($ctrl_status[0])}
    } else {
    return ($ctrl_status)
    }
}
```

}

Switch, я так понимаю на несколько условий работает. На что заменить switch, что эта часть кода была корректна?

Comment: Приведите более полный кусок кода.

Comment: Что по вашему должен делать код?

Comment: У меня есть 3 вида вхождения статусов 3 статуса 2 статуса и 1 статус, эта часть кода должна при вхождении одного статуса, присваивать этот статус одному параметру, при вхождении 2 статус двум параметрам, у меня сейчас получается,что при вхождении 1 статуса он присваивает ко всем параметрам один и тот же статус. Изменил код, спасибо большое за то что отозвались. Очень благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, switch в этом коде ни на что не надо заменять (смысл его непонятен), а надо просто убрать.

```
$ctrl_status = & "$ssacli" "ctrl $($ctrid_type)=$($ctrlid) show status".Split() | Where-Object {$_ -match "controller status|cache status|battery.*status"}
    if ($ctrl_status.Length -eq 3) {
            "main" {return ($ctrl_status[0] -replace ".+:\s")}
            "cache" {return ($ctrl_status[1] -replace ".+:\s")}
            "batt" {return ($ctrl_status[2] -replace ".+:\s")}
    } elseif ($ctrl_status.Length -eq 2) {
            "main" {return ($ctrl_status[0])}
            "cache" {return ($ctrl_status[1])}
    } elseif ($ctrl_status.Length -eq 1) {
            "main" {return ($ctrl_status[0])}
    } else {
        return ($ctrl_status)
    }
}
```

*PS. Я не знаком с синтаксисом PowerShell, но думаю, что делать три раза `return` в одной ветке там нельзя точно так же, как и в других языках. После первого `return` другие два уже не сработают.*

Comment: прошу прощения, а как же быть с $ctrl_part? компоненты. дополнил код, извините, я просто не опытен задавать вопросы, прошу прощения что по частям все спрашиваю. Так как в дальнейшем вызывается  $ctrl_part Write-Host - ом

Comment: Не знаю, как быть с $ctrl_part. Какова роль этой переменной?

Comment: return вполне валидно использовать. Просто завершится функция.

Comment: @JK_Action Так я это и написал.